# How to return data that has particular columns in every _source dictionary in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch query which is extracting data from the following fields `"_source": ["data.service","data.vpn","data.policyid","data.srccountry1"]`. While using the search function which gives only max hits of 10,000 I observe that in a lot of hits all _source values are not present.

Query :

```
{ 
"size" : 10000,
"_source": "_source": ["data.service","data.vpn","data.policyid","data.srccountry1"], 
      "query":{
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match_phrase": {"data.action": "accept"}},
            {"match_phrase": {"location": "192.168.0.1"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

In some of the hits `data.vpn` is not present or `data.srccountry1` is not present. How can I write a query where I need the hits to have all the `_source field` values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to check if your fields which you need is present in the documents or not.